# ENOENT error when trying to emulate Ionic made iOS app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying the Ionic framework.Everything ran smoothly but 
when I tried to emulate an iOS app

```
macbook$ sudo ionic emulate ios
```

I got the following error:

```
Password:

....

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-6 simulator
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/macbook/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/9F89ED64-0748-4A65-92DF-611110E9D4C4/system.log'
Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args: launch,/Users/macbook/Documents/workspaceionic/MyTestApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator/MyTestApp.app,--devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6,--stderr,/Users/macbook/Documents/workspaceionic/MyTestApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--stdout,/Users/macbook/Documents/workspaceionic/MyTestApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit
Error: /Users/macbook/Documents/workspaceionic/MyTestApp/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

do you have any ideas about what could be wrong?
I'm using Yosemite and Node version is 0.12.7. iOS apps from XCode emulate fine

**EDIT:**
if I open the project with XCode and emulate it, it works.

Comment: Does the file it states in the error message exist?

Comment: No. The  folder 9F89ED64-0748-4A65-92DF-611110E9D4C4 doesn't exist either

Answer (score 1):

no need for `sudo`

`ionic emulate iOS`

is the correct statement

Comment: I'm having same problem as op, and if i try `ionic xxx` i get a `-bash: ionic: command not found` error. I must use `sudo ionic xxx` instead. (I'm actually on OS X El Capitan building for iOS 9)

Answer (score 1):

There are apparently issues with running Node 0.12.x and Ionic. I'm running into this issue, myself, in my c9.io account... the dev environ wants 0.12.x, but Ionic requires 0.10.x. See Anil Singh's response in this thread for more information: [With Node 0.12.2 and npm 2.7.4 ionic installation error on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882974/with-node-0-12-2-and-npm-2-7-4-ionic-installation-error-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission issue, it's resolve my problem,

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/Code/ionic-app/
```